# Additional characters to change the tag "title" in the code behind

Tags: asp.net, html, code-behind

I need to change the page title according to its contents, then I perform the following:

HTML (aspx):

```
<title id="titleOfPage" runat="server"></title>
```

Code behind

```
titleOfPage.Text = news.Title;
```

But when I run the page, I see the following:

```
<title>
    My custom title completely
</title>
```

My custom title has the following characters "0D" + "0A"+ "09", or ASCII eguivalente "013"+ "010""009" (carriage return + new line + horizontal tab) at the start, and "0D" + "0A"at the end.

How I can do to display correctly?, I need it to search engines (Google, Bing, ...).

`news.Title` is correct, no spaces, its value is "My custom title completely".

Thanks

**Edit**

I tried `titleOfPage.Text = "My custom title completely";` and I get the same result

**Edit II**

I tried creating a property in the codebehind, but the result is the same, however if I put the property on a tag "div" text looks good.

codebehind:

```
...
public string TitleOfPage { get; private set; }
...

TitleOfPage = news.Title;
```

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title><%= TitleOfPage %></title>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <div><%= TitleOfPage %></div>
    ...
</body>
```

Result:

```
<title>
    My custom title completely
</title>

<div>My custom title completely</div>
```

**EDIT III**

First sorry for not putting this before. in my example I did not fully included the tag `head`, the full head tag is as follows `<header runat="server">`, I do not know why but if I remove `runat="server"`, it works correctly.

Then appeared the property "innerText" to the title:

HTML:

```
<title id="TitleOfPage" runat="server"></title>
```

Codebehind:

```
TitleOfPage.InnerText = news.Title;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying ASP.NET is adding those characters to your title? That doesn't sound right.

BTW, I would remove your server-side title tag and setting `Page.Title` instead.

Looking at some of my web pages, I see some of them do have newlines places around my title text. If that's all that's happening, then I don't see a problem. White space is essentially removed by the browser and this causes no adverse effects. Is this causing a problem?

Comment: @Jonathan Wood. I get the same result

Comment: What does `news.Title.Length` return?

Comment: `news.Title.Length` return 25 characters

Comment: Well, I count 26 characters in the text you said it contains, so I continue to think you haven't provided the complete picture. What does `Page.Title = "This is a test"` do?

Comment: I think the better question is how are you wanting it to render?

Comment: @Chad: Yeah, if it's just a matter of newlines being added, that probably is a better question.

Comment: @andres: Your question could be *much* shorter and clearer but it appears you are just concerned about whitespace being added to your title text. This causes no bad effect for search engines. What is your concern?

Comment: @andres: So in addition to not providing all the information about the problem, it looks like you're not going to provide how you fixed it either. And no upvote to boot! What a waste of time...

Comment: Ok, well your comment does not apply to a discussion. I regret the loss of your time.